# ROS2 : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘rclpy._rclpy’

Tags: ros, ros2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I’m new in using linux and i’ve been trying to run ros 2 on linux 20.04.
I’ve followed the “Installing ROS 2 on Linux” tutorial :
https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Linux-Install-Binary/

All have been fine until i run the command

```
ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener
```

and i get the following traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/home/moutalib/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/lib/demo_nodes_py/listener”, line 11, in
load_entry_point(‘demo-nodes-py==0.9.3’, ‘console_scripts’, ‘listener’)()
File “/home/moutalib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/ init .py”, line 490, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File “/home/moutalib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/ init .py”, line 2854, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File “/home/moutalib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/ init .py”, line 2445, in load
return self.resolve()
File “/home/moutalib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/ init .py”, line 2451, in resolve
module = import (self.module_name, fromlist=[‘ name ’], level=0)
File “/home/moutalib/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/lib/python3.8/site-packages/demo_nodes_py/topics/listener.py”, line 16, in
from rclpy.node import Node
File “/home/moutalib/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/node.py”, line 41, in
from rclpy.client import Client
File “/home/moutalib/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/client.py”, line 22, in
from rclpy.impl.implementation_singleton import rclpy_implementation as _rclpy
File “/home/moutalib/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/impl/implementation_singleton.py”, line 31, in
rclpy_implementation = _import(’._rclpy’)
File “/home/moutalib/ros2_foxy/ros2-linux/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/impl/ init .py”, line 27, in _import
return importlib.import_module(name, package=‘rclpy’)
File “/home/moutalib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/ init .py”, line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘rclpy._rclpy’
```

I have tried to look on other topics but couldnt find a solution that works for me.
I would be grateful if anyone can help me debug this problem.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355064/ros2-:-modulenotfounderror:-no-module-named-%E2%80%98rclpy._rclpy%E2%80%99./) by [BadrMt](https://answers.ros.org/users/55829/badrmt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-06-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-16**:\

> I’ve followed the “Installing ROS 2 on Linux” tutorial [..]

*which* one? Always include a link.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-06-20**:
In the future a much more helpful error message should be shown: https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/pull/580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

your stack trace looks extremely suspect to me, it looks as if you built ros2 with python3.8 but it seems you're in a conda environment that is using python3.7? I may be wrong about the environment, but you definitely want to make sure you're using a single python version

If we look at the last two lines of the stack trace

```
File “/home/moutalib/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/ init .py”, line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘rclpy._rclpy’
```

The python 3.7 importlib is going to be looking in all of the python3.7 install paths for rclpy, but it will not find it because rclpy was installed with python3.8

---

Originally posted by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) with karma: 553 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BadrMt](https://answers.ros.org/users/55829/badrmt/) on 2020-06-19**:
Hello,
Thank you for your response.
Can you tell me what to do in order to have a single python version ? Should i uninstall conda ?

**Comment by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on 2020-06-19**:
make sure your conda environment is deactivated using the command `conda deactivate`. Then things should work. Unfortunately up to ros2 eloquent (and I assume foxy) the build system will only ever look at your system python, and wouldn't work with virtual environments or conda.

**Comment by [BadrMt](https://answers.ros.org/users/55829/badrmt/) on 2020-06-20**:
Thank you very much. This solve dmy problem and made me realise an important detail that i was missing about why did i have (base) written before my terminal line.

**Comment by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on 2020-06-20**:
i'm glad we could get this resolved! Could you click the checkmark to indicate this answer solved your issue?

**Comment by [dm](https://answers.ros.org/users/86185/dm/) on 2021-10-02**:
I have the same issue but when I type conda deactivate, it says that conda: command not found
Can you help me with this?

**Comment by [Roy Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/159705/roy-lim/) on 2023-07-10**:
check ~/.bashrc if conda command is allowed